# Get name of class for Attribute usage in Python Astroid / Pylint

Tags: python, pylint

I have the following files:

```
# in models.py
class User(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

# in util.py
def get_user():
  return User(name="tom")

# in views.py
from util import get_user
get_user().name
```

I want to detect all Attribute usages for the name attribute on the User model. So `get_user().name` would be flagged as one such usage, since `get_user` returns a role `User` object.
Is there an easy way to do this using Astroid only preferably?

Comment: Just a syntax correction, I know, not super relevant, but should not `name = None` be `self.name = None`?

Comment: @Mr.Zeus I updated the example to be more explicit

Comment: Sorry 'bout that, I'm a perfectionist, could you tell?